# Azure DevOps Classic Release Pipeline Test Stage Not Triggered Following Completion of Dev

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

All,

I have created a Azure DevOps Classic Release Pipeline with a Dev stage followed by a Test stage.

The trigger for the Test stage has been set as "After Stage" with the Dev stage being selected as the stage it should follow.

When I run the release pipeline manually the Test stage does not run when the Dev stage completes which is what I was expecting.

It seems pretty straightforward so I'm struggling to work out how to diagnose why the Test stage does not follow on from the Dev.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a few screenshots? What you describe should work. But regardless, if possible move to YAML pipelines, the classic release is on its way out (slowly).

Comment: There's a schedule on the release pipeline. If I disable it the trigger kicks in. Are triggers disabled for manual releases if a release pipeline has a schedule?

Comment: Again, send a screenshot. It's hard to imagine what you're looking at. Or what you have or haven't selected when you queue a new release.